# Adding java arguments to a multicraft server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In my multicraft server (***multi***­craft, it's for ***mine***­craft) I am running out of PermaGen memory space ([This](http://pastebin.com/zxTpTa3K) is my crashlog if you want it). According to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003855/increase-permgen-space), I need to add the argument

```
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=128m
```

to launching the jar file.

How do I do this? My host will do something if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to contact your hosting provider, unless there is already an option to set permgen space in the UI, you can't set it. Multicraft does NOT allow you to specifiy command line arugments, otherwise you could take more RAM than you are supposed to, as well as do some other evil things.

Answer (score 0):

According to the multicraft documentation (here:  http://www.multicraft.org/site/docs?view=troubleshooting#28  )  It is possible to change the permgen (and other startup information) by editing the jar config file.

These files are in the 'jar' directory; additionally, these are updated whenever you use the 'update minecraft' function as a superuser.  So *do* make backups.

If your multicraft installation is provided by someone else - i.e. a server host - and you didn't install it yourself - you may not have access to these files.  But for those of us who do - i.e. those of us who run multicraft on our own servers - this is the answer that the multicraft authors provide.

I'm actually editing this file on my own server to add additional suggestions in THIS thread: http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/recent-updates-and-snapshots/2256694-1-8-server-thread-warn-cant-keep-up  - so I have altered more than just permgen.  This is more a "how to alter the start on multicraft" answer than a "permgen" answer.  I hope this helps someone else.